# sQl Join on case statement taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

When trying to join two tables using a case statement, results take too long. Table structure looks like below. Table A may or may not have an alphanumeric  .

```
Table A
--------
AdminId
-------------
Kerry, John (A1234567)
K,John 
..

Table B
---------
Id        | Name
-----------------
1234567    Kerry, John
1234568    K,John
...
```

Join is on a case statement that looks like below

```
CASE 
           WHEN adminid  LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND dbo.udf_GetNumeric(AdminId)=B.id THEN 1
           WHEN adminid  NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'  AND adminid = B.Name THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END = 1
```

The function udf_GetNumeric just picks the numeric sequence from alphanumeric. When I comment the line

```
WHEN adminid  NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'  AND adminid = B.Name THEN 1
```

The query only takes a few seconds. is there a better way of writing the join? Such that I can improve performance?

Comment: added `sql-server` tag due to the usage of a "regex" in the `LIKE` condition.

Comment: Why not just (adminid  LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND dbo.udf_GetNumeric(AdminId)=B.id) or (adminid  NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'  AND adminid = B.Name) ? Not that it may improve performance.

Comment: You've left out too many details to really evaluate efficiency (complete SQL, JOIN logic, INDEXes, and the such). But given that things go well without that CASE, probably the answer is "no". You're evaluating a derived expression and using it to filter the data. No index can help you on that, I fear.

Comment: I wonder if a function based index can help.

Comment: @user2672165 In SQL Server? Unlikely.

Comment: It is poor database design to hold both the name and Id in one column. The id should be extracted and placed into it's own column. If the Id isn't always known, use a nullable column. Then the name column could be called 'name' which makes more sense.

Comment: Is the `adminid  NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'  AND` part even necessary? Could you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Turophile: the tables should be redesigned.  Your options include:
1. Create an AdminId column (which doesn't have to be PK and doesn't need to have a Not NULL cosntraint).  Populate this with the numeric data you're looking for using your udf_GetNumeric.
2. If the data is coming into the table as-displayed, create a calculated column using the udf_GetNumeric.  Make it a persisted column and stick an index on it.
3. If you can't modify the structure of the existing table, create a 2nd table (B_Supplement) and put your AdminID in there, and join it to table B using table B's primary key.

Your biggest improvement will be with the table redesign, but you can optimize your Case statement as well.  The Case statement can be improved by switching your 1st and 2nd When-branches as that takes the function execution out of the process if the adminID matches directly.

Also, it doesn't seem like your results will change if you take out the "Not Like '%0-9%'.

This one's a bit riskier depending on how the UDF is written, but you might be able to take out the LIKE '%0-9%' without any impact as well.

And finally, you can get better performance in your comparison (it will be what's referred to as SARG-able; see: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ for more details) if you switch the comparison around in the 1st When so that it's "B.id  = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(AdminId)"  Thus, I would re-write the Case as:

```
    CASE
       WHEN adminid = B.Name THEN 1
       WHEN adminid  LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND B.id  = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(AdminId) THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
```

The riskier version of this would be:

```
  CASE
       WHEN adminid = B.Name THEN 1
       WHEN B.id  = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(AdminId) THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
```